# Remove Specific Object in the Chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

Goal:
Display the chart without displaying "Bikes", "Bikes - Internet Sales Amount" and "Bikes - Internet Tax Amount". Please review at pictures. 
However, "Bikes", "Bikes - Internet Sales Amount" and "Bikes - Internet Tax Amount" shall be available in the list but not in the chart.

Problem:
I do not know how to remove "Bikes", "Bikes - Internet Sales Amount" and "Bikes - Internet Tax Amount" in the chart. I tried but I failed.

Information:
*I'm using SQL server 2012
*The data source is SSAS from AdvenctureWorks.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{ 
    [Measures].[Internet Standard Product Cost], 
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], 
    [Measures].[Internet Total Product Cost], 
    [Measures].[Internet Tax Amount] 
} ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY 
{ 
    ([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Customer].ALLMEMBERS * [Product].[Product Categories].[Product].ALLMEMBERS ) 
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM 
    [Adventure Works] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the chart, select chart properties, select filters

You can add multiple filter conditions that will be reflected in your chart..

If you want to remove entire catergories then you should add the filter onto your series..

Let me know if you need me to expand on this answer.